# How to re-order the existing xml layout views programmatically

Tags: android, xml, layout, dynamic

I already have one xml file called `my_times.xml`. 
It contains views like, `TextView`, `EditText`, `Spinner` and `ImageView`.
Also I am using one web-service, which tells me the order of these views.
For Example, for one of my form field, say FirstName is appearing in the order 1, so this view will come in the first place of my form. If admin on the server changes this order to 2, then FirstName will come on the screen at second position and so on.
Is there any way to rearrange/reorder the existing xml layout, without disturbing the existing 
xml layout.
My sample `my_times.xml` looks something like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
<TextView.../>
<EditText..../>
<TextView.../>
<Spinner.../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please suggest me the ideal way to rearrange these existing views.
There are about 4 to 5 such screens which contains the form like fields that I want to rearrange/reorder dynamically based on the web=service response..

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually guess it but appears like a blink in my mind and tried the following solution and it worked...!
As I told earlier that my Web-Service was giving me the order of those form fields.
I made one method, which is returning me the order exactly like its on server.
Using this method I simply used the following two methods to re-order my views :

```
private void removeExistingViewsFromXML(){
        lnrTimesContainer.removeView(tv1);
        lnrTimesContainer.removeView(edt1);
        lnrTimesContainer.removeView(tv2);
        lnrTimesContainer.removeView(spn1);
    }
```

And after getting the order and depending on the condition, I used the method :

```
lnrTimesContainer.addView(tv2);
lnrTimesContainer.addView(spn1);
```

Thats it...! :-)